# Extending a Structure Array

Tags: c, struct, realloc

Would this be the proper way to extend a structure array?

```
typedef struct { int x,y,z;} student_record;

int main(){

student_record data_record[30];       // create array of 30 student_records
num_of_new_records = 5;

data_record = realloc(data_record,(sizeof(data_record) + (sizeof(student_record)*num_of_new_records)));

// do I now have an array of 35 student_records???
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No - you can't assign to an array.  Your code won't even compile - did you try it?

If you want to `realloc()` you need to have used `malloc()` (or one of its relatives):

```
student_record *data_record = malloc(sizeof(student_record) * 30);
```

You probably shouldn't be assigning the return value of `realloc()` back to the original variable, either. If it fails for some reason, you'll lose the original pointer and leak that memory.

Comment: So what method should I use?  Create a new temp array of larger size and copy over, then malloc() the first to the size I want and copy back again?

Comment: Don't use arrays if you want to use `realloc()`.  Use pointers and `malloc()`.

Answer (score 1):

You should follow the pattern of calloc'ing the initial size and then using realloc when necessary. Safe practice for realloc'ing need to include assigning the initial value returned to a temporary variable and over-writing the first after verifying that there are no errors. Something like this:

```
 student_record *data_record = malloc(sizeof(student_record) * 30);
 student_record *tmp;

 // need larger size
 if ((tmp = realloc(data_record, new_size)) == NULL)
    perror(); //possibly exit as well since you're out of memory
 else
   data_record = tmp;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can only use realloc on objects that are on heap (dynamically allocated) thus you have to malloc first.

```
typedef struct { int x,y,z;} student_record;

int main()  
{
    student_record *data_record = malloc(sizeof(student_record)*30);
    assert(data_rocord);
    data_record = realloc(data_record, sizeof(student_record)*35);
    assert(data_record);
    free(data_record);
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

}
```